# I need to paste something when ever I press Alt 2 times. Is there a way to do it in C# form?

Tags: c#

I am making an application in winForms which copy the email address in text field and pastes it where ever my cursor is placed. The problem is there is no double press keyboard key in IDE. Also, Is there a way to make the paste work outside my application?

string email="";

```
    private void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        email = textBox1.Text;

    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
        {
            button1.PerformClick();
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the clipboard process built in to Windows?

Comment: Windows uses CTRL+C to copy and CTRL+V to paste.  Why don't you use those shortcuts?

Comment: Sorry guys, I am new to coding. Can you just add some code? I can understand by looking at the code

Comment: Sorry man.. StackOverflow isn't a code writing service!  If you want to do a double ALT combo for paste (silly.. but whatever), you will need to keep the state of the last key press and see if it was also an ALT.  You will also need to make sure the last ALT press wasn't a combo with other keys.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the standard Windows keyboard shortcuts and the clipboard?

Comment: Guys, What I am trying to make is an app like double@ for Iphones. My email address is long so I don't want to type it everytime. In c# to press a key we can use e.KeyCode==Keys.Alt. For two keys to press simultaniously we can use e.KeyCode==Keys.Alt && e.KeyCode==Keys.K. But I want to press alt two times. I can't write e.KeyCode==Keys.Alt && e.KeyCode==Keys.Alt right. That's where I am stuck. About clipboard all I can think about is click on the button to copy and use ctrl + V to paste. I will try it though. But that's not the app I want to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like everyone else said I really don't understand why you are doing this, but with that said....

```
public bool isAlt;

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode==Keys.Alt)
    {
        if(isAlt == true)
        {
            //This is second consecutive alt key pressed, run code and unset isAlt at 
            //end
        }
        else
        {
            //This is first alt key pressed, set isAlt
            isAlt = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Alt wasn't pressed, set isAlt
        isAlt = false;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this and there is likely a better solution, but I'm pretty sure this should work.